# How can I restart Docker Container when Jenkins do build?

Tags: spring, docker, jenkins, cicd

I'm doing Spring boot CI/CD task.
I use Docker and put Jenkins on it and Jenkins makes my Spring project auto build.

The Deployment is working well, but there's a problem.
If I did't restart docker container, the new build did not apply.
So when I check swagger-ui, there no changes.
If I have to restart docker, I can see the changes on swagger-ui

What should I check in this case?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v238r.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I3OLQ.jpg)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GkTrn.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Unless you restart the container , it will be using the same image .

you can refer here

https://serverfault.com/questions/745244/does-docker-restart-use-the-latest-image-or-the-one-the-container-was-created-wi

Not sure how you are configuring the docker build, or are you using any orchestration tools . Please try to add configuration you are using to have more clarity to the question.

Make sure you have a force-pull turned on in the configuration if you are not  changing the image tags with each builds

you can also try to add restart-policies to your docker build . The default is NO , means it will not automatically restart.
docker run  --restart always

Comment: Oh sorry my explanation is not enough. I added something, I have no idea that it is enough though.